# Error, Start Gammu Service

Tags: gammu

I got error when i trying to start gammu service in Windows Local Services.

[image: Error 27 Gammu]

The service can work if only i open in command prompt with only this command, and the command prompt must alive as long as the service is on
[image: The Working]

Is there is another way, to start service? So we no more start from CMD...?

This the log, from `smsdlog` when i entered the command : `gammu-smsd -c smsdrc`.  So the service work. But still i cannot start in windows service local

> Tue 2015/05/26 22:07:41 gammu-smsd[6596]: Connected to Database odbc: aptikad on aptikad_sms 
>   Tue 2015/05/26 22:07:41 gammu-smsd[6596]: Created Windows RW shared memory at 0000000002DE0000
>   Tue 2015/05/26 22:07:41 gammu-smsd[6596]: Starting phone communication...
>   Tue 2015/05/26 22:07:50 gammu-smsd[6596]: Inserting phone info
>   Tue 2015/05/26 22:19:49 gammu-smsd[6596]: Read 1 messages

Comment: Is there something in the SMSD log file?

Comment: `Tue 2015/05/26 22:07:41 gammu-smsd[6596]: Connected to Database odbc: aptikad on aptikad_sms
Tue 2015/05/26 22:07:41 gammu-smsd[6596]: Created Windows RW shared memory at 0000000002DE0000
Tue 2015/05/26 22:07:41 gammu-smsd[6596]: Starting phone communication...
Tue 2015/05/26 22:07:50 gammu-smsd[6596]: Inserting phone info
Tue 2015/05/26 22:19:49 gammu-smsd[6596]: Read 1 messages`

Comment: thats the log, if i enter the command: `gammu-smsd -c smsdrc` in CMD

Comment: I mean if you start it from service.

Comment: It doesn't has any log. :(

Comment: Did you configure it?

Comment: I'm sorry, did you mean configure on `Gammurc` and `smsdrc` ?
If so, off course I did. I configure it, so that it work when i enter `gammu-smsd -c smsdrc` from CMD. 

The problem is, after i installed the service. And tried to start it, it display error like the picture above

Comment: I should recommend you run this service on  Linux rather than on Windows for some reason is more stable...

Comment: no more time. I need it as soon as possible now. :'(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solutions:

1. you have to set it as **Set as System DSN** (not User DSN)
   [image: Set as System DSN]

2. or if you want to use User DSN, **Run service as a user** not using local account
   [image: Run service as a user]

Answer (score 1):

If it helps, I experienced a lot of problems installing it on Windows yesterday, and I documented successes and failures. It may help you: https://stephenmonro.wordpress.com/2015/06/26/gammu-on-a-windows-computer-for-sms-database/